# Azure app - Different behavior between release configuration and remote debug configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, remote-debugging

I'm developing a web application running on Azure, which has to create a database for every new user registration.

In the Register() method of the controller, launch the CreateOrUpdateToElasticPoolAsync() method to run an API call that creates the new database within an elastic pool.
Then, with the Initialize() method, a number of methods populate the new database with the sample data.

```
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var response = await AzureRestAPISqlDatabase.Databases.CreateOrUpdateToElasticPoolAsync("databaseName", "elasticPoolName");
                var databaseEF = new BO.DatabaseEF();
                databaseEF.Inizialize();

                return RedirectToAction(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted ? "InfoConfirmEmail" : "Error");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

An example of a method included in Inizialize() is as follows:

```
class Cliente
{
    public static void Add()
    {
        var db = new DAL.Context(new BO.Account().ConnectionString);

        var cliente = new Models.Cliente
        {
            DataModifica = DateTime.Now,
            Sistema = true,
            Tipo = Models.ContattoTipo.Cliente
        };
        cliente.Sede.Destinatario = "(nessuno)";
        cliente.Destinazione.Destinatario = "(nessuno)";
        db.Clienti.Add(cliente);
        db.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

The Add() method of the Cliente class creates a Context class
passing the connectionString parameter similar to the following:

```
"Server=tcp:XXXXXXXX.database.xxxxxx.xxx,XXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

While the code for the constructor of the Context class is as follows:

```
public partial class Context : DbContext
{

    public Context(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Cliente> Clienti { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if I run the application in remote debug configuration and set a break point in the Add() method of the Cliente class, run F10 until the end of the method, everything works, no errors.
If, even in remote debug configuration, do not set breaks, I get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Database 'b6eaae45-8aa6-43ef-9de0-f8d22701e8f0' already exists. Choose a different database name.
```

Same error even if I run the application in release configuration.

Where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As they are sharing the same connection string, it will create always the same database.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand. Who shares the same connection?

Comment: the way you're trying to solve won't work. This method to create if not exists is the Model First Approach.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I do not know where to begin to study this solution.

Comment: a new database for each user? I am just wondering, why would you want that..perhaps you simply want to create a new for the user...I want to be sure that you really are trying to create a new database for each user.

Comment: Please log the connection string and check the connection string after the exception occurred and check the database name in connection string. You will know whether the database is already created or not.

Comment: @woller What you're looking for is multi tenant database

Comment: @Jay yes, a new database for each user.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Thank you. I have not found the solution yet.

Comment: @Amor The database creates it in an elastic pool through an API call. In the connection string, the database name is the same as the one previously created. The connection string is correct because if I run the app in remote debug configuration it works, if I run it in the release configuration does not work. I can not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the clarifications you have provided, and the following point..

*Now, if I run the application in remote debug configuration and set a break point in the Add() method of the Cliente class, run F10 until the end of the method, everything works, no errors. If, even in remote debug configuration, do not set breaks, I get the following error:*

I have never tried to create a new database for each user ( I keep thinking about the huge cost of such an application ), but, I have created new databases over code. If it works when you do F10 individually, then, as the error, then, may be you are calling the database creation twice (like a double call).

Here is what I imagine is happening.

1. You call the database creation (Register). Database gets created.
2. Then, you are calling Register again, and trying to create the same database. Run into this error. In this second step, perhaps due to some error mechanism, there is a second call to Azure happening which is forcing the code to create the db again with the same name.

My solution would be, in the Register method, I would first check if a database with such a name exists, and only proceed if it does. at least this should help you avoid the above error.